# how can we send a text file from client to the server?

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to send a file from client to the server using C socket programming. but in the server side I am not able to receive the file which I had sent from the client. I am attaching the codes below.

server:

```
/*  Create a connection queue and wait for clients.  */

listen(server_sockfd, 5);
while(1) {
    char ch;

    printf("server waiting\n");

/*  Accept a connection.  */

    client_len = sizeof(client_address);
client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_address,cli);
    if(client_sockfd > 0)
    printf("client is connected\n");
/*  We can now read/write to client on client_sockfd.  */
  char *fh;
    recv(client_sockfd,fh,1024+1,0);
    printf("server recieved %s",fh);

/*        read(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
    ch++;
    write(client_sockfd, &ch, 1); */
   return close(client_sockfd);
}
}
```

Comment: This might be a better question on stackoverflow.

Comment: There are several undefined variables in the code (e.g. `file` and `message`). Please update this code to something that at least compiles.

Comment: 'char *buffer[1024];' - did you really want an array of 1024 pointers?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the return of `recv`

```
if ((nbytes = recv(client_sockfd,fh,1024+1,0)) > 0)
```

and end your buffer with `'\0'`

```
fh[nbytes] = '\0';
printf("server recieved %s",fh);
```

Also, is not a good idea to use magic numbers like `1024+1`